# Page view in iText RUPS

Tags: itext

The iText RUPS screenshot below (taken from an [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549541/best-tool-tool-for-inspecting-pdf-files)) shows a page view between the document tree and the xref tab.
 How can that view be made visible in iText RUPS 5.5.9 on Windows? [image: iText RUPS]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't be made visible in iText RUPS 5.5.9 because this functionality has been removed in July 2009 (https://github.com/itext/rups/commit/ec6063). So if you want to use that rendering, you'd need to use a very old version of RUPS.

However, if you quickly want to open the PDF in an installed PDF viewer on your OS, use the shortcut ALT+O or the option in the File menu.