# How to make a pdf parser in python from scratch

Tags: python, pdf

I am looking to make a PDF parser from scratch using Python (or) any leads to tweaking existing libraries/algorithms.

Comment: Tell us what you already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167) you can find some nice tools for your need, like:

- **pdfrw**: Read and write PDF files
- **slate** : Active development. Simplifies extracting text from PDF files
- **PyPDF2** : Active development. Split, merge, crop, etc
- **PDFMiner** : Active development. Extracting text, images, object coordinates, metadata from PDF file

And there is more in this link.

Comment: You will also need a PDF inspector, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549541/best-tool-tool-for-inspecting-pdf-files. Good luck!