# Export PDF as XML and fill the tags with Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi, pdf, acrobat

I cant get trough this without some help.

I'm trying to export a PDF document to XML/XDP using the correct menu in Acrobat Reader.

I can see all my fields in the document in Acrobat Reader and can fill them by code with Delphi except 3 tags.

The problem comes when I try to export the fields' contents to XML and is that the XML does not contain three of the field tags it ought to contain. They are simply not in the XML generated by Acrobat Reader but as I've said the fields are for sure usable and not hidden in the PDF form itself.

For example :

> Name : `<Name></Name>`
>
> First name : `<Firstname></Firstname>`
>
> Date :  Missing in XML file

What could explain the fact that the three fields are not exported to XML whereas all the rest are, and how could I investigate what the cause of the difference is?

I hope I gave you enough informations to try to help me.

Comment: So what is it that you are asking exactly?  Are you saying that the `Name` and `Firstname` **do** appear as tags in the XML Reader produces but that the `Date` field does not?  If so, I'm not sure how readers could help, without access to the original PDF document.

Comment: Yes that's it. Some fields are simply missing in the XML/XDP
I know that's a bit tricky to answer without viewing the original PDF but I really can't send it on the web because of its privacy. Don't you have any small ideas of what is happening in this kind of case ? :'(

Comment: Ok, but PDF documents can have such wide variations of contents, I think the chances of being able to reproduce this problem without access to your document are zero.  If you can't make the entire document available, could you just make a part which does show the problem available?  I assume you generate the PDF document yourself?  Btw you might try looking at e.g. this q for tools for analying PDFs:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549541/best-tool-for-inspecting-pdf-files

Comment: I don't generate the PDF myself. It is a high class PDF for doctors bills in Switzerland. But as I said, only permitted doctors can get access to this pdf file. I really don't know what to think about it. Ther is something like 100 fields and only are not in the XML file when I export it.

Comment: "and only are not"  Is there a word missing from this phrase?

Comment: and only **3** are missing in the XML

Comment: Ah, ok.  Do you have access to the full version of Acrobat, the version which enables you to create your own forms?  I don't know how familiar you are with PDF Forms, but when you create a new field, there is a whole collection of attributes that can be set to control its behaviour, and very possibly there is something in the attributes for your 3 problem fields that accounts for the difference between those 3 and the others.

Comment: This question as currently written isn't useful. It's too specific to your situation, is lacking the relevant details needed to reproduce the problem, and contains none of the code involved. You're asking us to speculate about a problem cause. It's the equivalent of calling your auto repair shop and saying *There's a funny noise coming from under the hood of my car. What's wrong?* and expecting a whole bunch of guesses, and that's not how SO works.  As such, it has no value to future readers of this site, and therefore shouldn't be here. Voting to close for that reason.

Comment: Also, when you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.

Comment: @KenWhite I sincerely apologize that my question do not follow the rules.
I'm pretty new to StackO but I know and understand the rules for the posts. The simpliest answer I can provide to you is that I spent a lot of time trying to make it work just to find out that I can't do anything to fix this issue. I was just hoping, as you say, that someone could have maybe encountered a similar problem and could have speculate to help me. Best regards

Comment: @MartynA Thank you very much for your help. I will upvote your answer because of all the help you tried to provide to me even knowing that my question isn't following the rules and is too specific to answer. I will try to find out if the problem is due to the attributes as you suggest.

Comment: @VirussInside:  Thanks.  As I've said in my answer, it's worth spending some time getting up to speed with Acrobat's Form & Field objects - depending on what your ultimate goal is, you may even find that you don't need XML at all.

Comment: I've noticed a behaviour of PDF fields that may account for what you are seeing - see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hesitate to post this as an answer, because it will not directly answer your q
but it may point you in the right direction to do some self-help.

Unless your PDF file is corrupt, the only rational explanation for your 3 problem fields, and it can only really be something to do with their attributes stored in the PDF file.  As you'll see from the extract from the Acrobat Formms interface below, each field has a large number of possible attributes, and I'm confident that you should be able to identify the difference(s) which account for your problem field's different behaviour.

AFORMAUTLib_TLB.Pas is the import unit
I generated from the Forms plug-in for Acrobat8 (which is a bit old now, but I
don't think that matters).  The extract from it shows the interface for an Acrobat IField and the
umpteen properties/attributes which can be set for a field in an Acrobat form.

So, in your position, if I absolutely had to use the XML generated by Reader, what I would do would be to write some code
using the objects in AFORMAUTLib_TLB to dump the properties of the form's fields
and see if I could identify whatever differences there are between your three
problem fields and the rest.  Working with the objects in AFORMAUTLib_TLB is very
straightforward - basically, there is a FormApp object which allows you to open
an Acrobat Form and provides access to its IFields collection, which contains
an IField instance for each field defined on the form.  All this is thoroughly
documented in the Acrobat SDK available from Adobe's site.

If you spend an hour or two playing with the Forms interfaces, I'm fairly sure you'll end up being tempted to avoid using Reader's XML output and simply generate your own from the `IField` objects in the form.  That's assuming you actually need the XML at all of course.

I imagine - but don't know for sure (and don't want to install Reader to find
out) is whether Acrobat Reader has the same plug-in for handling for fields.
Obviously, if it doesn't, you are out of luck with this approach.

Good luck!

PS:  Once you have an `IField` interface to a field of interest, you can tweak its attributes and contents at run-time, so if you can find the difference(s) which is causing the problem, it could be very straightforward
to apply a run-time fix.

Also btw the interface objects in the import unit may it easy to turn a plain
PDF document into a form and optionally fill it in, it that's what's you need.  I'm not sure whether anything has been done to inhibit this functionality in Reader, though - if you get into doing a lot of forms work, a copy of the full version of Acrobat is pretty much indispensable.

**Update:**  I'm not sure whether the facility Acrobat 8 has for exporting form data (under Forms | Manage Form Data | Export Data | save as type : XML) is functionally identical to what you are using in Reader, but simple observation of its behaviour is that if, at the time the Export Data function, a field is empty, no XML tag for it is included in the exported XML.  This is regardless of whether the form has been saved to disk since the field was emptied.  So, if that is the case with your form, a possible work-around would be to temporarily set the field's value to something non-empty, export the PDF to XML and then abndon the change.

```
// Type Lib: D:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 8.0\Acrobat\plug_ins\AcroForm.api (1)
// IID\LCID: {7CD06992-50AA-11D1-B8F0-00A0C9259304}\0

// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: IField
// Flags:     (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {673E8454-7646-11D1-B90B-00A0C9259304}
// *********************************************************************//
  IField = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{673E8454-7646-11D1-B90B-00A0C9259304}']
    function  Get_Name: WideString; safecall;
    function  Get_Value: WideString; safecall;
    procedure Set_Value(const pbstrVal: WideString); safecall;
    function  Get_IsHidden: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_IsHidden(pIsHidden: WordBool); safecall;
    function  Get_IsTerminal: WordBool; safecall;
    function  Get_Type_: WideString; safecall;
    function  Get_IsReadOnly: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_IsReadOnly(pIsRO: WordBool); safecall;
    function  Get_IsRequired: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_IsRequired(pIsReqd: WordBool); safecall;
    function  Get_PrintFlag: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_PrintFlag(pIsPrint: WordBool); safecall;
    procedure SetBorderColor(const bstrColorSpace: WideString; GorRorC: Single; GorM: Single;
                             BorY: Single; K: Single); safecall;
    procedure SetBackgroundColor(const bstrColorSpace: WideString; GorRorC: Single; GorM: Single;
                                 BorY: Single; K: Single); safecall;
    function  Get_BorderWidth: Smallint; safecall;
    procedure Set_BorderWidth(pVal: Smallint); safecall;
    function  Get_Alignment: WideString; safecall;
    procedure Set_Alignment(const pVal: WideString); safecall;
    function  Get_CharLimit: Smallint; safecall;
    procedure Set_CharLimit(pVal: Smallint); safecall;
    function  Get_DefaultValue: WideString; safecall;
    procedure Set_DefaultValue(const pVal: WideString); safecall;
    function  Get_IsMultiline: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_IsMultiline(pVal: WordBool); safecall;
    function  Get_IsPassword: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_IsPassword(pVal: WordBool); safecall;
    procedure SetExportValues(arrExportVal: OleVariant); safecall;
    procedure SetJavaScriptAction(const bstrTrigger: WideString; const bstrTheScript: WideString); safecall;
    procedure SetSubmitFormAction(const bstrTrigger: WideString; const bstrTheURL: WideString;
                                  theFlags: Integer; arrFields: OleVariant); safecall;
    procedure SetResetFormAction(const bstrTrigger: WideString; theFlags: Integer;
                                 arrFields: OleVariant); safecall;
    procedure SetButtonIcon(const bstrFace: WideString; const bstrFullPath: WideString;
                            pageNum: Smallint); safecall;
    function  Get_CalcOrderIndex: Smallint; safecall;
    procedure Set_CalcOrderIndex(pVal: Smallint); safecall;
    function  Get_BorderStyle: WideString; safecall;
    procedure Set_BorderStyle(const pVal: WideString); safecall;
    procedure SetForegroundColor(const bstrColorSpace: WideString; GorRorC: Single; GorM: Single;
                                 BorY: Single; K: Single); safecall;
    procedure PopulateListOrComboBox(arrItems: OleVariant; arrExportVal: OleVariant); safecall;
    function  Get_Editable: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_Editable(pVal: WordBool); safecall;
    function  Get_Highlight: WideString; safecall;
    procedure Set_Highlight(const pVal: WideString); safecall;
    function  Get_Style: WideString; safecall;
    procedure Set_Style(const pVal: WideString); safecall;
    function  Get_TextFont: WideString; safecall;
    procedure Set_TextFont(const pVal: WideString); safecall;
    function  Get_TextSize: Smallint; safecall;
    procedure Set_TextSize(pVal: Smallint); safecall;
    procedure SetButtonCaption(const bstrFace: WideString; const bstrCaption: WideString); safecall;
    function  Get_ButtonLayout: Smallint; safecall;
    procedure Set_ButtonLayout(pVal: Smallint); safecall;
    function  Get_NoViewFlag: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_NoViewFlag(pVal: WordBool); safecall;
    property Name: WideString read Get_Name;
    property Value: WideString read Get_Value write Set_Value;
    property IsHidden: WordBool read Get_IsHidden write Set_IsHidden;
    property IsTerminal: WordBool read Get_IsTerminal;
    property Type_: WideString read Get_Type_;
    property IsReadOnly: WordBool read Get_IsReadOnly write Set_IsReadOnly;
    property IsRequired: WordBool read Get_IsRequired write Set_IsRequired;
    property PrintFlag: WordBool read Get_PrintFlag write Set_PrintFlag;
    property BorderWidth: Smallint read Get_BorderWidth write Set_BorderWidth;
    property Alignment: WideString read Get_Alignment write Set_Alignment;
    property CharLimit: Smallint read Get_CharLimit write Set_CharLimit;
    property DefaultValue: WideString read Get_DefaultValue write Set_DefaultValue;
    property IsMultiline: WordBool read Get_IsMultiline write Set_IsMultiline;
    property IsPassword: WordBool read Get_IsPassword write Set_IsPassword;
    property CalcOrderIndex: Smallint read Get_CalcOrderIndex write Set_CalcOrderIndex;
    property BorderStyle: WideString read Get_BorderStyle write Set_BorderStyle;
    property Editable: WordBool read Get_Editable write Set_Editable;
    property Highlight: WideString read Get_Highlight write Set_Highlight;
    property Style: WideString read Get_Style write Set_Style;
    property TextFont: WideString read Get_TextFont write Set_TextFont;
    property TextSize: Smallint read Get_TextSize write Set_TextSize;
    property ButtonLayout: Smallint read Get_ButtonLayout write Set_ButtonLayout;
    property NoViewFlag: WordBool read Get_NoViewFlag write Set_NoViewFlag;
  end;
```