# Tool to explore PDF structure and internals on macOS?

Tags: macos, pdf

I'm looking for a (free, GUI) tool to explore the internals and structure of PDF files on macOS (10.14.1). It looks like PDFXplorer from OS solutions (http://www.o2sol.com/pdfxplorer/overview.htm) would meet my needs, but no Mac version is available. I do not have Adobe Acrobat Pro. Surely, with the broad use of macOS in desktop publishing, there must be a tool to inspect the innards of a PDF! Any thoughts?

Comment: Clint, tool recommendations are deemed off-topic on Stack Overflow as they are highly subjective (as "the best") and tend to attract opinions and spam. See the [help/on-topic]. That said: can I interest you in taling a look at Python? It has a number of very good (3rd party) libraries that allow easy access to the internals of a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

You may find an answer here, which includes lists of tools for parsing PDF data.

[Best tool for inspecting PDF files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549541/best-tool-for-inspecting-pdf-files)

Generally, in desktop publishing, the data streams of PDF are of little interest. Any problems, and the PDF will be re-made from the source artwork files, or edited/adjusted with Acrobat's preflight utility, or with a third-party tool like [PitStop](https://www.enfocus.com/en/pitstop-pro).
But this is without any user awareness of the actual data objects.