# Printer works with Gilroy from excel, but not from Gilroy created from vb application

Tags: vb.net, itext

I created an application that my company use to print PDF. i used itextsharp library to create it.
when i try to view the printed pdf in Windows or MACos, the font is displayed correctly. When i try to print it with printer connected to Windows pc it works correctly. But when i try to print it with printer connected to MACos pc it doesn't works correctly. In the same pdf there are fonts created with excel and with my application. the font created with excel works correctly but the font created with my application doesn't print correctly.
[For adobe, the fonts are the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2qyg.png)

I used vb.net to create application and this is code:

```
Dim NewFont As iTextSharp.text.Font = FontFactory.GetFont(Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts) + "\Gilroy-Light.otf", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
```

Why the font doesn't print correctly? Maybe vb.net application can not intefce with MAC? or is itextsharp bug? Could be some type of permiss?

Comment: Did you embed the font in the PDF?

Comment: yes, i did but the result doesn't change

Comment: Can you check that it was actually embedded? If the Adobe tool doesn't tell you, PDFXplorer (or one of the other tools) as linked to in [Best tool for inspecting PDF files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47855653/1115360) will let you find out.